# Xcode 4.3.3 - Error Undefined Symbols

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

hy all,
I am building an application to create a simple tableview, with a search bar on top to search between the elements of the table.
I have followed a tutorial and no coding errors were found, but when building, it always fails showing the following message:

```
Ld /Users/gouyoun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ERCDictionnary-atjolczeormaykcscwvnhlxdcnvk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ERCDictionnary.app/ERCDictionnary normal i386
cd /Users/gouyoun/Desktop/ERCDictionnary/ERCDictionnary
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -L/Users/gouyoun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ERCDictionnary-atjolczeormaykcscwvnhlxdcnvk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/gouyoun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ERCDictionnary-atjolczeormaykcscwvnhlxdcnvk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/gouyoun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ERCDictionnary-atjolczeormaykcscwvnhlxdcnvk/Build/Intermediates/ERCDictionnary.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ERCDictionnary.build/Objects-normal/i386/ERCDictionnary.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/gouyoun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ERCDictionnary-atjolczeormaykcscwvnhlxdcnvk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ERCDictionnary.app/ERCDictionnary
```

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OverlayViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in tableView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

```
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OverlayViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in tableView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm a newb in OBjective C, any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the line the error occured ?

Comment: @Sabbath It's a link error. There's no specific line of code given.

Comment: In the 'Show the issue navigator' , you can see the build error with an icon which is displayed as a red circle , right ?

Comment: Single click the error in the 'Show the issue navigator' , the line that the error occurred will be shown in the code browser area and high-lighted .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its done, it only needed to remove the files and re-add them later, it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Your tableView class refers to a class called `OverlayViewController` which is not in your project.

Comment: No i have an OverlayViewController.h and OverlayViewController.m files in my project

Comment: That's what the error says. Try cleaning the build and compiling again. Check that OverlayViewController.m is included in your target.

Comment: or the class name has a typo in the file.

Comment: I made sure that it is included and i made sure there is no typo ... any ideaS?

Comment: Is it included in your _target_ and not just included in your project? (Look in the top level project. You'll see "Projects" and "Targets." In the latter switch to the "Build Phases" tab and look in the "Compile Sources" section.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the exact same error. It occured because I had 2 xCode Projects open, an Dragged & Dropped a class from one project to the other one. I checked "Copy to project" and the files where in the new projects folder. But it crashed every time.

I deleted the classes and **IMPORTED** them into the project and then it worked... So be careful when using Drag'n'Drop!